# methods accessibility while synchronization in java

Tags: java, synchronization

Suppose there are **four methods(m1, m2, m3, m4)** and **two threads(t1, t2)**, now I want to know below-

**1. Non-static case:**

a) Suppose **all methods are synchronized but non-static** and say t1 is accessing m1, then can t2 access m2/m3/m4 ?

b) Suppose **m1 & m2 are synchronized** and **m3 & m4 are non-synchronized**, **all are non-static**, now say t1 is accessing m1, then can t2 access m2/m3/m4 ?

**2. Static case:**

a) Suppose **all methods are synchronized & static** and say t1 is accessing m1, then can t2 access m2/m3/m4 ?

b) Suppose **all methods are static** and **m1 & m2 are synchronized** and **m3 & m4 are non-synchronized**, now say t1 is accessing m1, then can t2 access m2/m3/m4 ?

**3. Mixed Case:**

a) **m1&m2- static & synchronized**, **m3&m4- non-static & non-synchronized**. Now say t1 is accessing m1, then can t2 access m2/m3/m4 ?

b) **m1- static & synchronized**, **m2- static & non-synchronized**, **m3- non-static & synchronized**, **m4- non-static & non-synchronized**. Now say t1 is accessing m1, then can t2 access m2/m3/m4 ?

Can someone please answer and explain on above ? Thanks !

Comment: Rather than asking us to "suppose", it would be much clearer if you wrote some code.

Comment: With non static method it is important on what instance you call it.

Comment: same instance @talex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
  a) No.
  b) Only `m3` and `m4`.
2.
  a) No.
  b) Only `m3` and `m4`.
3.
  a) Only `m3` and `m4`.
  b) Yes.

Comment: @aman-gupta, see my answer for the explanation part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916688/methods-accessibility-while-synchronization-in-java/55917495#55917495

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19):

> A synchronized statement acquires a mutual-exclusion lock on behalf of the executing thread, executes a block, then releases the lock. While the executing thread owns the lock, no other thread may acquire the lock.

In the case of a synchronized *non static* method the lock is acquired on the monitor associated with the instance the method was invoked on.

In the case of a synchronized *static* method the lock is acquired on the monitor associated with the `Class` object of the class in which the called method is defined.

See the [Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1) section in the JLS.